# keep an event waiting for another event completion - old shool

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I need to do this but without async/await keywords (my app is compiled with 
 `.NET Framework 4.0`)

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    await tcs.Task;
    WelcomeTitle.Text = "Finished work";
}

private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tcs?.TrySetResult(true);
}
```

any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `tcs.Task.Wait();`?

Comment: Why are we using tasks here at all, just use a manual reset event or something. unless this of course is an over simplified example

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually attach a continuation to the task. This is the kind of burden that async-await was designed to alleviate.

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    tcs.Task.ContinueWith((_) =>
    {
        WelcomeTitle.Text = "Finished work";
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}

private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tcs?.TrySetResult(true);
}
```